# Run both addEventListener for "keyup" and "click" simultaneously (or two separate events)

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, innerhtml

I am making a simple conversion calculator (beginner level) where the input can be a number (eventListener "keyup") and then output is instant. However, the user might want to change the units and then the output needs to reevaluate the number.

I have installed JQuery as well, so a JQuery option is also a possibility.

```
element = document.getElementById("inputVelocity");
element.addEventListener("keyup", convert);
function convert() {
  let vi = parseFloat(element.value);
  let unit = document.getElementById("units").value;
  let result;
  if (unit === "ms") {
    result = vi;
  }
  if (unit === "kmh") {
    result = vi / 3.6;
  }
```

This then returns the result back to HTML:

```
document.getElementById("ms").innerHTML =
    vi.toFixed(2) + "<span> ms<sup>-1</sup></span>";
  document.getElementById("kmh").innerHTML =
    (vi * 3.6).toFixed(2) + "<span> kmh<sup>-1</sup></span>";
```

However, maybe the user wants to change from m/s to km/h so they then click the selector   from the HTML:

Currently, the output works - I can select one of the units and the output for "unit" is correct. But if the user changes their mind, the innerHTML isn't picking up the new selection.

The desired outcome:
User inputs 20 m/s
Output = 20 m/s and 72 km/h

The user then changes the unit from m/s to km/h (but keeps the number the same):
output = 5.5 and 20 km/h

Comment: "*simultaneously*" - javascript is *single threaded* so only one line of javascript can be running a time.    This doesn't seem to be your issue/question, but wanted to point out the use of "simultaneously".

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, probably a poor choice of words. Wanting the eventListener to check for keystrokes and/or a click within the form.

Comment: Can you provide some HTML so we can see how the inputs fit together?  Ideally in a snippet with all the code needed to demonstrate the issue - see [mcve].

Comment: I have actually just fixed it... I was calling an incorrect ID... sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution is two IDs and (one for the number and the other for the selected units) then two addEventListener...

```
element = document.getElementById("inputVelocity");
secondElement = document.getElementById("units");
element.addEventListener("keyup", convert);
secondElement.addEventListener("click", convert);
```

This solved the issue easily.

Comment: to be clear, 2 id's aren't needed. rather, you just need to call the same function on a different event, which can be done with or without id's even existing.

Comment: Ahh, that is handy! But in this case one ID was in a select element and the other in the input element so I guess this worked out that way. But it is handy to know you can do this too.